# Featured image is not uploading

Tags: post-thumbnails

[image]

[image]

1. I click the set featured button
2. try to add image in set featured option
3. when I click set featured image button the image doesn't upload

I have already updated my theme and wordpress theme after this issue. Tested on different web browsers but issue is not getting resolved. What should I do?

Comment: Did you check the console? Are there any errors? When you open network tab, when you upload a button does it make new request? You also should check server error logs. How big is the file? Disk is not full?

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Switching to the unedited default Theme (Twenty Sixteen, etc.) for a moment using the WP dashboard to rule out any theme-specific issue.
> 2. Maybe a third party plugin causes a js conflict/error on the admin screen. Please try to deactivate all plugins and check if this solves
>      the issue. If yes activate them one by one again to find the
>      incompatible plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Same issue happened with me when i was using below code in my js file in my plugin . This might help authors.

```
// Enable Media Upload 

if(function_exists( 'wp_enqueue_media' )){

    wp_enqueue_media();

}else{

    wp_enqueue_style('thickbox');

    wp_enqueue_script('media-upload');

    wp_enqueue_script('thickbox');

}
```